# How to make the player's weight deform a rope bridge?

Tags: unity, 2d, rope-physics, hinge-joint

I'm making a 2d game, and I want my character to deform my rope bridge with physics effects on the jointed structure when they walk over it.

Right now, the player can stand on the bridge, but it doesn't react to where their weight is pressing down on it:

[image: player walking on bridge]

Here's how I've configured my player avatar:

[image: player inspector]

And how I've set up the segments of the bridge using hinge joints:

[image: bridge]

[image: inspector of joint]

Finally, here's the player control script I'm using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerPlatformerController : PhysicsObject
{

    public float maxSpeed = 7;
    public float jumpTakeOffSpeed = 7;

    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    private Animator animator;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    protected override void ComputeVelocity()
    {
        Vector2 move = Vector2.zero;

        move.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded)
        {
            velocity.y = jumpTakeOffSpeed;
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump"))
        {
            if (velocity.y > 0)
            {
                velocity.y = velocity.y * 0.5f;
            }
        }

        bool flipSprite = (spriteRenderer.flipX ? (move.x > 0.01f) : (move.x < 0.01f));
        if (flipSprite)
        {
            spriteRenderer.flipX = !spriteRenderer.flipX;
        }

        animator.SetBool("grounded", grounded);
        animator.SetFloat("velocityX", Mathf.Abs(velocity.x) / maxSpeed);

        targetVelocity = move * maxSpeed;
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PhysicsObject : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float minGroundNormalY = .65f;
    public float gravityModifier = 1f;

    protected Vector2 targetVelocity;
    protected bool grounded;
    protected Vector2 groundNormal;
    protected Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    protected Vector2 velocity;
    protected ContactFilter2D contactFilter;
    protected RaycastHit2D[] hitBuffer = new RaycastHit2D[16];
    protected List<RaycastHit2D> hitBufferList = new List<RaycastHit2D>(16);


    protected const float minMoveDistance = 0.001f;
    protected const float shellRadius = 0.01f;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        contactFilter.useTriggers = false;
        contactFilter.SetLayerMask(Physics2D.GetLayerCollisionMask(gameObject.layer));
        contactFilter.useLayerMask = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        targetVelocity = Vector2.zero;
        ComputeVelocity();
    }

    protected virtual void ComputeVelocity()
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        velocity += gravityModifier * Physics2D.gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        velocity.x = targetVelocity.x;

        grounded = false;

        Vector2 deltaPosition = velocity * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector2 moveAlongGround = new Vector2(groundNormal.y, -groundNormal.x);

        Vector2 move = moveAlongGround * deltaPosition.x;

        Movement(move, false);

        move = Vector2.up * deltaPosition.y;

        Movement(move, true);
    }

    void Movement(Vector2 move, bool yMovement)
    {
        float distance = move.magnitude;

        if (distance > minMoveDistance)
        {
            int count = rb2d.Cast(move, contactFilter, hitBuffer, distance + shellRadius);
            hitBufferList.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                hitBufferList.Add(hitBuffer[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < hitBufferList.Count; i++)
            {
                Vector2 currentNormal = hitBufferList[i].normal;
                if (currentNormal.y > minGroundNormalY)
                {
                    grounded = true;
                    if (yMovement)
                    {
                        groundNormal = currentNormal;
                        currentNormal.x = 0;
                    }
                }

                float projection = Vector2.Dot(velocity, currentNormal);
                if (projection < 0)
                {
                    velocity = velocity - projection * currentNormal;
                }

                float modifiedDistance = hitBufferList[i].distance - shellRadius;
                distance = modifiedDistance < distance ? modifiedDistance : distance;
            }


        }

        rb2d.position = rb2d.position + move.normalized * distance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that your character's rigidbody is set to "Kinematic". A kinematic rigidbody isn't driven by the physics engine. It has no weight and thus does not exert any force on other objects it stands on. So it won't interact with your rope bridge at all.

When your player-characters rigidbody is no longer kinematic, you must no longer move it by directly changing its `rb2d.position`. When you change the position like that, you are not moving the character, you are teleporting it. That can lead to weird problems in regards to collision detection and game physics. When you are moving an object which is supposed to interact with the physics engine, always do so by [adding forces](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) to its rigidbody, or when that gets too fiddly, by changing the [velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) of its rigidbody. But only change the position directly when you actually mean to make it disappear in one location and and reappear in a different location.

Also another hint about the bridge itself: connect the bridge parts using [Spring Joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpringJoint.html) instead of hinge joints.

This quick PoC I just created needs some more tweaking of the rigidbody and spring settings to reduce the jitter, but it should give you an idea how it can work:

[image: Bridge animation]

Edit: I forgot that you have a 2d project. In that case you would of course use [Spring Joint 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpringJoint2D.html).

I am looking forward to playing your game.